# Tomcat 6 init.d/SysV script

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, tomcat6

I have a custom Tomcat 6 installation on an Ubuntu box. I'm trying to get it to start on system boot, but can't seem to find a script to put in `/etc/init.d`. Where can I find one? Or how do I write it myself?

Answer (score 1):

If you need more sophisticated script, then you can attempt to use `/etc/init.d/tomcat6`, which is provided by tomcat6 package:

```
mkdir tomcat6-pckgsrc
cd tomcat6-pckgsrc
apt-get source tomcat6
cat tomcat6-6.0.28/debian/tomcat6.init
```

To install as bootable System-V style init script use:

```
update-rc.d tomcat6 start 17 2 3 4 5 . stop 01 0 1 6 .
# update-rc.d -f tomcat6 remove
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/installing-tomcat-6-on-ubuntu/